# Can we make Lucene IndexWriter serializable for ExecutionContext of Spring Batch?

Tags: java, serialization, lucene, spring-batch

This question is related to [my another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701195/should-i-keep-lucene-indexwriter-open-for-entire-indexing-or-close-after-each-do).

To keep [IndexWriter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) open for the duration of a partitioned step, I thought to add `IndexWriter` in `ExecutionContext` of partitioner and then close in a `StepExecutionListenerSupport` 's `afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` method.

Challenge that I am facing in this approach is that `ExecutionContext` needs Objects to be serializable.

In light of these two questions, [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153686/no-valid-constructor-during-serialization) -- it doesn't seem feasible because I can't add a no - arg constructor in my custom writer because `IndexWriter` doesn't have any no - arg constructor.

```
    public class CustomIndexWriter extends IndexWriter implements Serializable {
    /*
private Directory d;
    private IndexWriterConfig conf;


        public CustomIndexWriter(){
            super();
            super(this.d, this.conf);
        }
        */
        public CustomIndexWriter(Directory d, IndexWriterConfig conf) throws IOException {
            super(d, conf);
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            input.defaultReadObject();
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream output) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            output.defaultWriteObject();
        }

    }
```

In above code, I can't add constructor shown as commented because no - arg constructor doesn't exist in Super class and can't access `this` fields before `super` .

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how but this syntax works in Spring Batch and `ExecutionContext` returns a non - null Object in `StepExecutionListenerSupport`.

```
public class CustomIndexWriter implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private transient IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter;

    public CustomIndexWriter(IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter) {
         this.luceneIndexWriter=luceneIndexWriter;
    }

    public IndexWriter getLuceneIndexWriter() {
        return luceneIndexWriter;
    }

    public void setLuceneIndexWriter(IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter) {
        this.luceneIndexWriter = luceneIndexWriter;
    }


}
```

I put an instance of `CustomIndexWriter` in step partitioner, partitioned step chunk works with writer by doing, `getLuceneIndexWriter()` and then in `StepExecutionListenerSupport` , I close this writer.

This way my spring batch partitioned step works with a single instance of Lucene Index Writer Object.

I was hoping that I will get a NullPointer if trying to perform operation on writer obtained by `getLuceneIndexWriter()` but that doesn't happen ( despite it being `transient` ). I am not sure why this works but it does.

For Spring Batch job metadata, I am using in - memory repository and not db based repository. Not sure if this will continue to work once I start using db for metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a parameter-less constructor.

E.g:

```
public class CustomWriter extends IndexWriter implements Serializable {
    private Directory lDirectory;
    private IndexWriterConfig iwConfig;

    public CustomWriter() {
        super();
        // Assign default values
        this(new Directory("." + System.getProperty("path.separator")), new IndexWriterConfig());
    }

    public CustomWriter(Directory dir, IndexWriterConfig iwConf) {
        lDirectory = dir;
        iwConfig = iwConf;
    }

    public Directory getDirectory() { return lDirectory; }

    public IndexWriterConfig getConfig() { return iwConfig; }

    public void setDirectory(Directory dir) { lDirectory = dir; }

    public void setConfig(IndexWriterConfig conf) { iwConfig = conf; }

    // ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Having taken a look at my own code (using Lucene.Net), the IndexWriter needs an analyzer, and a MaxFieldLength.

So the super-call would look something like this:

```
super(new Directory("." + System.getProperty("path.separator")), new StandardAnalyzer(), MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

So adding these values as defaults should fix the issue. Maybe then add getter- and setter-methods for the analyzer and MaxFieldLength, so you have control over that at a later stage.

Comment: there is no `super();` here in `IndexWriter` class.

Comment: What I am saying is that `IndexWriter` doesn't have a no - arg constructor so code with `super()` will not compile. That is why I have it commented.

Comment: Having taken another look in my own code, you need an analyzer. 
so it would be super(lDirectory, analyzer).

Let me edit my post.

Comment: As per larger program logic, there are no default values. I am using [partitioner of Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html) where I compute these values for each thread and a thread has to work on those values - no defaults.